# Why does file upload in Python Request throw 400 Error

Tags: python, python-requests, fastapi, locust

I am using the locust framework to test one of my endpoints (it takes an image file and tries to do magic on it). The server is running using FastAPI + gunicorn

This is my Curl command which gives the right response.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5002/my_endpoint/ -H "accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "input_file=@./path/to/myfile.jpeg"
```

And this is the corresponding python code in my locust file

```
class QuickstartUser(HttpUser):
    @task(1)
    def testClassifier(self):
        headers = {
                    'accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                  }

        files = {
                    'input_file': ('./path/to/myfile.jpeg', open('./path/to/myfile.jpeg', 'rb')),
                }
        response = self.client.request('post',"/my_endpoint", files=files, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()
        print(response)
```

Here is how I call the locust file

```
locust -f deploy/load_testing/locustfile.py --headless --host http://localhost:5002 -u 1 -r 2 --run-time 10s --stop-timeout 9 -L DEBUG --logfile ./locust.log
```

Can anyone help me here what I am doing wrong here?

```
  24   │     raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
  25   │ requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://localhost:5002/my_endpoint/
  26   │
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.clients.HttpSession.request) `files` should be a dictionary of `'filename': file-like-objects` but you are passing a tuple instead for the value. Change `files` to match the expected format

```
files = {
    'input_file': open('./path/to/myfile.jpeg', 'rb'),
}
response = self.client.request('post',"/my_endpoint", files=files, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Nope. still fails with the same error.

Comment: @AshwinKumar how did you do it, show us some code.

Comment: First post has the code.